# Pushing to a different git repo

Tags: git, github

I have a repo called `react`. 
I cloned it into a different repo locally called `different-repo`.

How can I then get `different-repo` to push remotely to different-repo because currently it is pushing to `react`.

Effectively I want to clone many times from `react` into different named repos but then when i push from those repos they push to their own repo.

Comment: `git remote add react <url>`

Comment: "...they push to their own repo"? I don't understand that.

Comment: Can you please edit your question properly.

Comment: @Christoph it makes sense because I clone from repoA into repoB but when I push a commit from repoB it pushes to repoA because repoB is basically repoA but with a different name. but I want to clone off repoA many times as it is boilerplate code and then I want to push to each individual repo remotely...make sense?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You have to add an other `remote`. Usually, you have an `origin` remotes, which points to the github (maybe bitbucket) repository you cloned it from. Here's a few example of what it is:

- `https://github.com/some-user/some-repo` (the `.git` is optional)
- `git@github.com:some-user/some-repo` (this is ssh, it allows you to push/pull without having to type your ids every single time)
- `C:/some/folder/on/your/computer` Yes! You can push to an other directory on your own computer.

So, when you

```
$ git push origin master
```

`origin` is replaced with it's value: the url

So, it's basically just a **shortcut**. You could type the url yourself each time, it'd do the same!

**Note**: you can list all your `remote`s by doing `git remote -v`.

### For your problem

> How can I then get different-repo to push remotely to different-repo because currently it is pushing to react.

I'm guessing you want to create a second repository, right? Well, you can create an other `remote` (or replace the current `origin`) with the url to this repo!

#### Add an other `remote` — recommended

```
git remote add <remote-name> <url>
```

So, for example:

```
$ git remote add different-repo https://github.com/your-username/your-repo
```

And then, just

```
$ git push different-repo master
```

#### Change the `origin` `remote`

```
git remote set-url <remote-name> <url>
```

So

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/your-username/your-repo
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to have different exclusions for different remotes? For example, pushing identical code to two separate repos each with a different README.md. I want each readme in my local repo for editing but need each remote to be unique.

Answer (score 4):

Here **different-repo** is the first repo from which you created/cloned the child repo **react**

So by default child repo  react will have its **default remote** as different-repo where you can push/pull changes.

Here child repo will maintain all the commit history of parent repo within its .git folder

If you want to push the changes to different repo from this react repo then add another remote(you can add as many as remotes here and also can delete the old remotes)

Add new Remote to react

```
git remote add <remote-name> <url>
```

If you want to remove the old remote

```
git remote remove <remote_name>
```

Answer (score 4):

[Git push to new repo from existing repo’s branch](https://medium.com/fuzzy-code/git-push-to-new-repo-from-existing-repos-branch-acb8bef3f7be)

This blog is to the point and explains it very well. Here is the snippet from the blog.

```
Go to current project: 
$ cd my-project

Add new origin (origin2): git remote add origin2 <git_url>
$ git remote add origin2 https://github.com/my-org/new-project

The following command pushes master branch of current repo to master branch of new repo with remote configured as origin2.
$ git push <remote_name> <remote_repo_branch>
$ git push origin2 master

The following command pushes specific branch (say dev) of current repo to master branch of new repo with remote configured as origin2.
$ git push origin2 <source_branch>:<destination_branch>
$ git push origin2 dev:master
Use --force (to forcefully push into that new branch if required)
$ git push origin2 <source_branch>:<destination_branch> --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if your current repo's branch that you want to push is called `master` and the remote repo branch where you push is called `main`, you should do `git push different-repo master:main`

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this answer in case someone wants to do it this way.

You can get the link of the repository, for example [https://github.com/<your-user-name>/<your-repo-name>.git](https://github.com/%3Cyour-user-name%3E/%3Cyour-repo-name%3E.git), and run the following command:

```
git push https://github.com/<your-user-name>/<your-repo-name>.git main
```