# Pulling one git repo's file into another repo

Tags: git

My repo contains a large toolchain that uses many functions, some of which were written by others. These other functions are in their own repos. When they are updated in their respective repos, is it possible for me to "pull" changes to these functions into my repo?

I see there's a way to do it with [git add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42084116/pushing-to-a-different-git-repo) but it appears this will pull all files from the other repo into my repo; not just the specific target functions. Is there a way to identify specific files to pull?

Comment: Please keep in mind that a commit in git is a snapshot of _all files_ in a repo

Comment: Git cannot easily [clone/fetch/pull](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+subdirectory) a subdirectory, it can only fetch full commits or chains of commits.

Comment: Normally they would put their functions in a package, which you would then use in your code. If they update their code you would just take the newest package. If you or they do not want to use packages, git submodules or integrating everything in one repo can be a feasible solution.